# New flyway migrations are not being applied (Springboot)

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using Springboot and have integrated flyway. I have 2 migration files.

1. V1__initialize_DB_a.sql
2. V2__new_tables_added_b.sql

When I start my springboot app with a clean DB, both the migrations are applied without any issue.
But when I start my app with only one file(V1__init_db.sql) and later restart the app after placing the new migration V2__new_tables.sql, the newer file is not applied.

**V1__initialize_DB_a.sql**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME
           FROM   sys.schemas
           WHERE  NAME = N'hose')
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA hose AUTHORIZATION [dbo]');
END
go

CREATE TABLE [hose].[obj_destination_group]
(
   id_destination_group INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   properties VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
go
```

**V2__new_tables_added_b**

```
ALTER TABLE [hose].[obj_destination_group]
    ADD is_enabled BIT NOT NULL default 1
GO
```

**Flyway_schema_histroy: After the run with V1 and V2**

[image: Flyway_schema_histroy: After the run with V1 and V2]

I spend a lot of time going through the doc, but no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post SQL scripts, and the results of: select * from flyway_schema_history; After a run with V1, and then once again after run with V1 and V2

Comment: @BorisKukec, I have posted the scripts and the content of flyway_schema_history. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I did not do any code change. I restarted my laptop(Macbook pro) for another issue. After the restart, the V2 migration file was detected and the migration changes were applied.

**Note:** I tried the `Invalidate caches / Restart` option in Intellij before restarting the laptop. It did not workout. Weird!